# Who is this person depicted on the “Ianua Nova” Latin textbooks?

Tags: ancient-rome, identification

My old Latin text book from school was called [Ianua Nova](https://www.amazon.de/dp/3525714041) and had a gentleman depicted on the front cover who looked like this:

[image]

I do not remember (if I ever knew) who he is. Considering that it is a Latin book, I assume it is a Roman or at least a Latin speaker. I have tried a reverse Google image search, but it only returned all kinds of unrelated busts. Quis est?

Comment: If you can find a copy online, most modern books including textbooks have credits to the cover designer on the first few pages, usually with all the other copyright information. If it was hardcover, illustration credits could be on the book jacket. It might at least have the photographer's name.

Comment: @creative-username Sadly no preview at Google Books, Amazon, or at the [publisher's website](https://www.vandenhoeck-ruprecht-verlage.com/themen-entdecken/schule-und-unterricht/latein/unterrichtswerke/latein-als-1.-oder-2.-fremdsprache/ianua-nova/8194/ianua-nova-neubearbeitung-teil-1-mit-vokabelheft?c=1865) (newer edition, same guy on the cover).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a Roman bust excavated at the French city of [Arles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arles) (see also [French Wikipedia on Arelate](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histoire_d%27Arles_%C3%A0_l%27%C3%A9poque_romaine)). Currently, it's part of the collection of the [Musée de l'Arles antique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mus%C3%A9e_de_l%27Arles_antique) (previously Musée Lapidaire). Initially, it was assumed that it's a bust of the Roman emperor [*Augustus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augustus) (*Octavian*). You can still find online sources describing the bust as one of [Octavian](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/a/aict/x-rm076/RM000_IMG0076?chaperone=S-AICT-X-RM076%20RM000_IMG0076;evl=full-image;quality=0;size=50;subview=download;view=entry). Nowadays, the bust is labeled as showing [***Gaius Caesar***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaius_Caesar), grandson (and adoptive son) of Augustus.

A modern photo of the bust:

[image: Bust of Gaius Caesar, photo by Carole Raddato from FRANKFURT, Germany / CC BY-SA (https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0)]

<sup>Source: [Wikimedia Commons, Photo by Carole Raddato from FRANKFURT, Germany](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Head_thought_to_be_of_Octavian_wearing_a_beard_as_a_sign_of_mourning_after_the_assassination_of_Julius_Caesar,_now_said_to_be_of_Gaius_Caesar,_grand-son_of_Augustus,_Mus%C3%A9e_de_l%27Arles_antique_(15158287595).jpg) / [CC BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0)</sup>

More photos (also from other busts showing Gaius Caesar) at Wikimedia Commons' [Category devoted to busts of Gaius Caesar](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Busts_of_Gaius_Caesar).

Another [photo of the bust with some additional details is available at Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/photos/roger_ulrich/11425556706) (i refrained from embedding it due to "all rights reserved").

Comment: Why does he look so odd from the side? I’m not sure how to describe it

Comment: Sunken cheek maybe?

Comment: @genzreadytoperish High cheekbones, and lighting.